# How clear textarea not using .val('')

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().before('<div class="comment_box_all"><div class="comment_user"></div></div>')
    var content = document.createElement("span");
   content.innerHTML=$(".textarea").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
    $('.comment_user').append(content);
});
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
 $(this).closest('.comment_panel').find('.textarea').val('')
});
 $('button').attr('disabled',true);
   $('.textarea').keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val().length !=0)
          $('button').attr('disabled', false);            
       else
          $('button').attr('disabled',true);
 });
```

```css
.comment_panel
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
}
textarea
{
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  }
button
{
  
  top:10px;
  left:330px;
 }
.comment_box_all
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#999;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_panel">
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add text..."></textarea>
    <button>Add comment</button>  
</div>
```

Could you help me how I can clear textarea after click button not using .val(''), because look, I would like disabled button when textarea is empty but this happen only in first add text, if I add text next time  in textarea is '' and button is active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the disabled class every time the `add` button is clicked as you were doing for the first time .

```
$(this).attr('disabled',true);
```

Add this line inside the button `onclick` function.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().before('<div class="comment_box_all"><div class="comment_user"></div></div>')
    var content = document.createElement("span");
   content.innerHTML=$(".textarea").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
    $('.comment_user').append(content);
});
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
 $(this).closest('.comment_panel').find('.textarea').val('')
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
 $('button').attr('disabled',true);
   $('.textarea').keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val().trim().length !=0)
          $('button').attr('disabled', false);            
       else
          $('button').attr('disabled',true);
 });
```

```css
.comment_panel
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
}
textarea
{
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  }
button
{
  
  top:10px;
  left:330px;
 }
.comment_box_all
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#999;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_panel">
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add text..."></textarea>
    <button>Add comment</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks, it's one step forward for me :) but if I set two or more spaces button is active and I can add next empty div

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Comment: @V.R To avoid spaces, you can use `trim()` on the textarea value before checking its length such that , button gets activated only when there is text and not spaces. I've updated the code in my answer, please check.

Comment: ooh, thanks trim() is something new for me, Thanks at all :)